# Why does react native still think my library is linked after unlinking? (0.60.x)

Tags: react-native

When upgrading to RN 0.60.x, I kept seeing this error message:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-localize (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-localize")
  - react-native-orientation-locker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-orientation-locker")
  - react-native-svg (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-svg")
```

This persists including after unlinking the library as indicated, and searching all project files for reference, and using `yarn remove` / `yarn add`.

How can I successfully unlink and get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case there were some commented-out Pod references in Podfile.

It appears that React Native can't tell that the lines are commented out:

```
#  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
#  pod 'react-native-orientation-locker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker'
#  pod 'RNLocalize', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-localize'
```

The fix was just to remove those lines entirely; that got rid of the error.